# How do I list a whl file as a dependency in setup.py

Tags: python, installation, pip, setuptools, setup.py

Note: I am very new to python (I come from a gradle maven world)

I read this blog:
https://underyx.me/2015/11/23/adding-an-unreleased-commit-as-a-dependency
And this one:
https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

and from my understand there is no way to specify external dependency (in my case tensorflow)

listed as an install file for pip
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

At least not using setup.py which is supposed to be the official way to setup any project.

So first of all is there any way to do this so someone can setup their project with a **single** command.

If not was is the easiest way to install this external dependency besides making a bash script that just runs pip install BLAH for all of my dependencies?

Comment: Google for a `requirements.txt`.

Comment: how helpful!  I did tons of google searches which lead me to create this question as I still did not have the knowledge needed

Comment: The question marked duplicate does not specify how to install a wheel. So I think we should still try to answer @dtracers question!